# urllib2.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: 'https>

Tags: django, uwsgi

I am using  nginx+django+uwsgi to depoy my app.

Now I get a weird error with https url issue

My django version is 1.6, uwsgi version is 2.0.4 and python version is 2.7.3

I can visit https url by django shell:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> response=urllib2.urlopen("https://www.baidu.com")
>>> data=response.read()
>>> print data
```

It works fine!!

If I start my app with uwsgi, I get an error `urlopen error unknown url type: https` with same code

I dont know why...

Comment: Can you post the full error/traceback?

Comment: r=urllib2.urlopen("https://wwww.baidu.com")      
  File "python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 423, in _open
    'unknown_open', req)
  File "python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1240, in unknown_open
    raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)

Comment: problem solved。I recompiled uwsgi